# Calendar using html css and javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, calendar

I have been trying to do a calendar using HTML, css and javascript. I have little experience with all three of them.

I havent got it to work with javascript, so sofar i have just created it with html+css and its a really ugly solution:

css:

```
#day {
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 85px;
    height: 85px;
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 5px;
    border-radius: 18px;
    }
```

html:

```
<div id="content">
<h1>November</h1>
<br>
<div id="day">
1
</div>
<div id="day">
2
</div>
<div id="day">
3
</div>
<div id="day">
4
</div>
<div id="day">
5
</div>
<div id="day">
6
</div>
<div id="day">
7
</div>
<br>
<div id="day">
8
</div>
<div id="day">
9
</div>
<div id="day">
10
</div>
<div id="day">
11
</div>
<div id="day">
12
</div>
<div id="day">
13
</div>
<div id="day">
14
</div>
<br>
<div id="day">
15
</div>
<div id="day">
16
</div>
<div id="day">
17
</div>
<div id="day">
18
</div>
<div id="day">
19
</div>
<div id="day">
20
</div>
<div id="day">
21
</div>
<br>
<div id="day">
22
</div>
<div id="day">
23
</div>
<div id="day">
24
</div>
<div id="day">
25
</div>
<div id="day">
26
</div>
<div id="day">
27
</div>
<div id="day">
28
</div>
<br>
<div id="day">
29
</div>
<div id="day">
30
</div>
</div>
```

I guess a for-loop would be good?
something like:

```
for(i = 0; i<30;i++){
   "code for creating day-boxes"
}
```

I found a couple of calendars online, but they are all so complicated and i doesnt really do what i want it to do.

Comment: What is your question? Because anyway you would not avoid for loop.

Comment: I recommend you try like [this](http://fullcalendar.io/)

Comment: My question is what to write instead of "code for creating day-boxes" and if my css-code will work.

Comment: fullcalendar.io is one of the calendars i found, and its superbig, i want to build it myself, i need to understand it all cause im not going to use it as a ordinary calendar.

Comment: Please never use the same id for multiple elements. Browsers will go crazy. If you want to group multiple elements and adress them via css use a class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure whether I get your question right, but shouldn't the following work?

```
var div = document.getElementById('content');

for(i = 1; i<=30;i++){
    div.innerHTML += '<div id=\'day\'>' + i + '</div>';   
}
```

[Here is my jsfiddle-example](http://jsfiddle.net/7sc82nbv/1/)

Note: dont use the same values (`day`) for id. Use the class attribute:

Change css to :

```
.day {
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 85px;
    height: 85px;
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 5px;
    border-radius: 18px;
}
```

And use this javascript code:

```
var div = document.getElementById('content');

for(i = 1; i<=30;i++){
    div.innerHTML += '<div class=\'day\'>' + i + '</div>';   
}
```

Comment: This was what i was looking for, it doesnt work perfectly but i think that is because of my other code i didnt show.
Thank you very much

Comment: Again, thank you very much! I got it work exactly like i wanted now and i changed the css as you suggested.

Comment: You're welcome. Have fun in the world of java-script :)

Answer (score 1):

For more advanced,stable and good documentation
 http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/